# coil properties

Tags: coil

I'm absolute not into electronics, but I have a question about coil properties. I have a circuit model where there are two coil. Based on information find on internet (I don't know if those are correct since I don't know a lot about electronics) one is a "coil tickler" and the other is a "step up" coil.
The only info i have about those are:

1) coil tickler: "6T #26", "1750T #45", "15T #32"

2) step up coil: "12T #33", "450T #45"

Could anybody help me to know what I should buy (or at least try to search) if I would to realize the circuit?

Thanks!

Comment: How about supplying a link to where you got the information from?

Comment: Realize *what* circuit?  Your specs only show wire sizes and numbers of turns.  You should be able to see there isn't nearly enough information here.

Answer (score 4):

Those numbers are telling you how many turns of what gauge wire to use. For example, "6T #26" means "six turns of 26 gauge wire". These are transformers, so they have multiple windings on the same core, which is why there are 2 or 3 pairs of numbers for each.

To realize these coils, you also need to know what sort of core should be used.

Comment: are there "standard core"? the circuit is a small photo flash, and there aren't any other reference

Comment: @user26137 unfortunately, no.